# How can I use ":" in LINQ group by conditions

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have 2 variable use like condition to group by in a data list
    string FileNo = "";
    string FileName = "";

Because FileNo and FileName may be blank
So when I have a data list looks like below:
    List DataList = new List();

I want to make sure FileNo and FileName not blank then I will use them in group by

I don't know how to embed them in LINQ syntax. Some etc looks like this:

```
var TotalDuplicate = GridList.GroupBy(x,y => "".Equals(FileNo) : x.FileNo, 
                                             "".Equals(FileName) : y.FileName
                        .Count(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: You just want to exclude items with blank `FileNo` and `FileName`?

Comment: why you used group by ?

Comment: Are you looking for *ternary operator*? `"".Equals(x.FileNo) ? "blank"  : x.FileNo`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to work around a false aliasing problem in a wrong way: rather than grouping by a single string composed of two parts `$"{FileNo}:{FileName}"`, group on a pair of strings the usual LINQ way:

```
var duplicates = GridList
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.FileNo, x.FileName })
    .Count(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 List<string> x = new List<string>() { "", "pp", "jj", "kjj", "", "" };
 foreach (string s in x.Select(xx => string.IsNullOrEmpty(xx) ? "Empty" : "Populated"))
 {
     Console.WriteLine(s);
 }
```

Output:

> Empty
>   Populated
>   Populated
>   Populated
>   Empty
>   Empty

What I did in the Select statement, you can do it also in the other linq statements (Where, Group etc)